# Cycling between different layers in R leaflet

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm using `leaflet` for `R`.
I have a map with hundreds of layers, and I want to cycle between them by pressing a button (maybe an `easyButton`) or a keypress.

This means that only one layer should be visible at a time, and that pressing the button would hide the current layer and show the next one (and at the last layer, start from the first).

Yes, I can do this with `baseGroups` and `addLayersControl`, but this requires moving the mouse and then clicking to select the layers and this can be slow, since I'm going to spend less than one second checking each layer anyway.

I'm no JS wizard, but I guess some sort of JS magic should be applied here. I'd like to avoid using `shiny` for such a simple applet.

Comment: Why not use a slider and use the slider value as input to a function that returns the layer. Call the function from within the plot statement.

Comment: Yeah, that would do, but I'd like to avoid using `Shiny` and I have absolutely no clue on where to start doing that by implementing custom `JS` snippets in `R` `Leaflet`.